# Drupal 8 - Nginx 1.10.1 Ubuntu - 14.04 - 404 Not found after installation is completed

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, ubuntu-14.04, drupal-8

I wonder if someone can help on this please. Actually I installed drupal 8 on ubuntu 14.04 (webserver nginx 1.10.1) wiht php-fpm.
Issue - I created a test site as a part of this installation set up and once this installation is finished, all I get is 404 Not found error.
What I can access -
http://hostname/sitename/index.php
This gives me the home page but when I try to access let's say (content, appearance, structure etc) all I get is 404 Not found.
I would be grateful if someone can help me on this.